# Ethernet card works only after soft reboot (82579V on Xubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, xubuntu, ethernet

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and I have a problem with my network card.

When I boot my PC, I can't use my network card: it doesn't appear in `ifconfig`. **But when I soft reboot, everything goes ok**.

In Xubuntu 16.04 I had no problem.

How can I fix this strange behavior?

Here my `lspci` output:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
```

My `lshw` when network is down:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       capabilities: ethernet physical
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       capabilities: ethernet physical
```

Any idea?
Thank you!

**Edit 2019-06-14 15.20:**

My `lshw` when network works:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 00:22:4d:7f:db:ca
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-5 ip=10.19.85.167 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:5a:c2:c1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:5a:c2:c1
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` is simply:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And here the output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` (with the network working) and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: @heynnema I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I see that might be a problem is that you've got a 1G ethernet device that's only connecting at 100Mb, which suggests a cabling problem, assuming that you're connecting to a gigabit network device. You should be using cat 5e or cat 6 cables.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 there is a new network configuration tool netplan. Netplan sometimes have some timeing issues.

Try to login and type

```
sudo netplan apply
```

and check ifconfig or ip address.

If your network is configured now, then you have this timeing problem.
If this is the case then you probably should read this
[Netplan does not apply at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019146/netplan-does-not-apply-at-startup)

Comment: Netplan is really only used in a server environment. Desktop environments should use NetworkManager.